# Mean square error for a quantizer - problem in integral

Tags: digital-communications, snr, quantization

There are similar questions about related problems that I honestly didn't understand. I believe this might be a lack of statistics knowledge of my part.
[Quantization error standard deviation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79309/quantization-error-standard-deviation)
[Error analysis for uniform quantization of uniform input](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55250/error-analysis-for-uniform-quantization-of-uniform-input)
[Signal to Quantization Noise ratio concept](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78538/signal-to-quantization-noise-ratio-concept)

I was reading David R. Smith's Digital Transmission Systems and in it I found the following derivation for the average error due to quantization.

[image]

I don't understand going from 3.8 to 3.9 It might be a math problem on my end.

The last two integrals will disappear, because they correspond to the overload regions of the quantizer, and we are assuming that the input signal, `x`, does not have values in that region, meaning, in the last 2 integrals $p(x)=0$ Thus, they are irrelevant.

Looking at just the first integral (ignoring the summation, because it doesn't bother me), for those that can't see the picture we have

$$ \int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j} (y_j - x)^2 p(x) dx $$

$x_j$ and $x_{j-1}$ correspond to input values of the quantizer that are the limits of a region in which the output of the quantizer is ${y_j}$. For example, if the input of the quantizer is between  2V to 3V let's say the output of the quantizer is 2.5V. $x_j$ for this case is 3V,$x_{j-1}$ is 2V and {y_j} is 2.5V $p(x)$ is just the probability that the input signal takes on the value $x$, so $p(2.3)$ is the probability that the input signal takes on the value 2.3V

Now for the following step we assume that $p(x)$ is a constant equal to $p(y_j)$ That I understood, but I can't understand how (I removed the constant probability from the integral to simplify) $$ \int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j} (y_j - x)^2 dx $$ turned into $$ \frac{(x_j-x_{j-1})^2}{12} * (x_j-x_{j-1}) $$

Where did the $y_j$ go?

Comment: It's a good question.  This treatment is not very good.  There needs to be an explicit relation that says something like $$ y_j = (x_j - x_{j-1}) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{x_j - x_{j-1}} \right\rfloor $$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the `floor( )` function (rounds down to the nearest integer).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thank you so much! I was feeling very stupid :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

$$y_j=\frac{x_j+x_{j-1}}{2}$$

you obtain

$$\begin{align}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}(y_j-x)^2dx&=\frac{(y_j-x_{j-1})^3-(y_j-x_{j})^3}{3}\\&=\frac{\left(\frac{x_j+x_{j-1}}{2}-x_{j-1}\right)^3-\left(\frac{x_j+x_{j-1}}{2}-x_{j}\right)^3}{3}\\&=\frac{\left(\frac{x_j-x_{j-1}}{2}\right)^3-\left(\frac{x_{j-1}-x_j}{2}\right)^3}{3}\\&=\frac{(x_j-x_{j-1})^3}{12}\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you! I did not find that assumption in the text. Rereading it I didn't find it again. I understand how it makes sense though.

Comment: @chilliefiber: I totally agree that this should've been mentioned somewhere in the book.